# Getting rake db:migrate error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rake, migrate

trying to add a NAME FIELD to my simple_form in rails

have added  $ rails generate migration AddNameToUsers name:string

which has been added to the user.db file & to my migrate file

```
class AddNameToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :name, :string
  end
end
```

BUT When i run rake `db:migrate` i get the following errors (also ran bundle exec...)

**rake aborted! An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:**

```
SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: email: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "email" varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:134:in `execute'
```

any ideas?

Comment: The error is right in the first line it says ` duplicate column name: email: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "email" ` so somewhere in your migration you already have a column called email. This needs to be resolved before you can run your db:migrate. Everytime you run the `db:migrate` command it will migrate your entire database and is finding that you have an existing field called email. Can you check if you have this. And if you have this you need to remove it. Because another migration is trying to add the column name `email`

Comment: thanks for connecting - to be honest @david not too sure where to look for. i have 3 files in my migrate file devise_create_users.rb & add_devise_to_users.rb & add_name_to_name_to_users.rb.  my user.db file has this -> attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :name  not sure how i would remove the email field. Iam trying to add a  name field to my  sign up form which works with a email & password field , since I added a name field doesnt work?

Comment: Please post your devise_create_users.rb and add_devise_to_users.rb migration files.

Comment: @Neil why you have delete the answer?.

Comment: I didnt delete the answer!

Comment: thing is theres another guy who has the same problem. so was coming to here to share the link

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience. Noticed there was a new devise .rb in the db/migrate folder. I deleted it and then refreshed and it worked.